# form object does not load in a template

Tags: django-forms, django-templates

I don t understand why I have this error as my code seems ok?
my form:

```
class NewListingForm(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField(label="Listing title", widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class' : 'form-control col-md-8 col-lg-8'}))
    description = forms.CharField(label='Description', widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'class' : 'form-control col-md-8 col-lg-8', 'rows' : 10}))
    enddate = forms.DateTimeField(
        label='Date ending auction',
        input_formats=['%d/%m/%Y %H:%M'],
        )
    category = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.Select(choices=categories_list))
    initialBid = forms.DecimalField(label='Inital bid amount', max_digits=12, decimal_places=2)
    photo = forms.ImageField(label='Image')
    active = forms.BooleanField(label='Is this auction is active?')
    edit = forms.BooleanField(initial=False, widget=forms.HiddenInput(), required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Listing
```

my views:

```
from .models import User, Listing, Bid, Wishing, Comment, Category
from .forms import NewListingForm
@login_required
def newlisting(request):
    form = NewListingForm()
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = NewListingForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            if form.cleaned_data["edit"] is True:
                form = form.save(commit=False)
                form.save()
                messages.success(request,
                                 'listing saved')  # message for inform user of success - See messages in html file
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("index", kwargs={'title': "list"}))
            else:
                return render(request, "auctions/newListing.html", {
                    "form": form,
                    "existing": True,
                    'title': "New Listing",
                })
        else:
            return render(request, "auctions/newListing.html", {
                "form": form,
                "existing": False,
                'title': "New Listing",
            })
    else:
        return render(request, "auctions/newListing.html", {
            "form": form,
            "existing": False,
            'title': "New Listing",
        })
```

my template newListing.html:

```
{% extends "auctions/layout.html" %}

{% block body %}
    <h2>{% if not listing_id %}Create Client {% else %} Edit {{ object.name }}{% endif %}</h2>
    <form id="create-edit-client" action="" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {% form %}
        <div class="form-actions">
                <input type = submit type="submit" value="Save" name="submit">
        </div>>
    </form>

{% endblock %}
```

my layout.html:

```
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>{% block title %}Auctions{% endblock %}</title>
        <link href="{% static 'auctions/styles.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Auctions</h1>
        <div>
            {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                Signed in as <strong>{{ user.username }}</strong>.
            {% else %}
                Not signed in.
            {% endif %}
        </div>
        <ul class="nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'index' %}">Active Listings</a>
            </li>
            {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'logout' %}">Log Out</a>
                </li>
            {% else %}
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'login' %}">Log In</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'register' %}">Register</a>
                </li>
            {% endif %}
        </ul>
        <hr>
        {% block body %}
            <h2>{{title}}</h2>

            {% if message %}
                <div>{{ message }}</div>
            {% endif %}
        {% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

I try to add {% load form %} but same type of error saying:
django.template.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: 'form' is not a registered tag library. Must be one of:
admin_list
admin_modify
admin_urls

thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just change {% form %} to {{ form }} seems working